# Trigger only some of the rules of a textbox in form validation with keyup event and cancel the event for the rest of them

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form in my application that I'm validating with the jQuery form validation plugin. One of the rules is of type remote to validate that the username doesn't exist already. I've been able to override the onkeyup event so the rule doesn't goes to the server for every letter I type in. The way I've done it is as below:

```
var validator = $("#frmSite").validate({
  onkeyup: function(element) {
    var element_name = jQuery(element).attr('name');
    if (this.settings.rules[element_name] != undefined) {
      if (this.settings.rules[element_name].onkeyup !== false) {
        jQuery.validator.defaults.onkeyup.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }
  },
  rules: {
    <%=txtUsername.UniqueID%>: {
      onkeyup: false,
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,              
      remote: function () {
        var params = {
          userName: userNameTextbox.val()
        };
        return {
          type: "POST",
          url: "services/security.asmx/UserNotExists",
          data: JSON.stringify(params),
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          dataFilter: function (data) {
            var msg = eval("(" + data + ")");
            if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d"))
              return JSON.stringify(msg.d);
            else
              return msg;
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
          }
        };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The problem I have is that now that the remote rule is triggered on the `onfocusout` event, whenever I click on something else in my page (for example, the logout button) the rule triggers. I've added the `onsubmit: false,` as part of the options of the `validate` function and a function to handle the click event of the submit button, but even with this the rule continues to trigger on the `onfocusout`. To control this I added a function similar to the one I set for the `onkeyup` so the rules are not triggered on the `onfocusout` either, but with this the only moment the user gets the validation message is after clicking on the submit button. However, I want to be able to notify the  user about the error as soon as possible (i.e. as soon as he finished typing the username). Is there a way to do any or all of the following:

1. To add a delay for the onkeyup so the rule is triggered some seconds after the user stopped typing in the username? This should be in a way that affects only to the username textbox as I don't want the delay to affect the other inputs in the form.

1a. If the above is possible, can be set in a way the affects only to the `remote` rule? So the `required` and `maxlength` validations are triggered during normal keyup, but only the `remote` one is after some seconds the user stopped typing in?

1. To make the `onkeyup` event to trigger only for the `required` and `maxlength` rules, but not for the `remote` one? So the `remote` rule is triggered only when user clicks on submit, but the other two are triggered on normal `keyup`

If there is any other possible way out, please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: With those requirements, you might as well just skip the plugin and write all of your validation functions from scratch.

Comment: I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel and save time if possible

Comment: Those requirements broke the wheel.

Comment: hahaha. I might have to write my own validation function then :S