# JQuery.validate - one rule on blur only; the rest should be normal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, blur

I've worked on a fiddle to show the simple validation that I'm trying to do for my user ID field:

1. Make it required (validate as aggressively as possible)
2. Set a minimum length (validate as aggressively as possible)
3. Set a maximum length (validate as aggressively as possible)
4. Run an AJAX call to ensure user ID doesn't already exist (*I want to only run this on blur*)

I'm not using the validate() - remote rule because I wanted to have a custom object returned instead of just a simple string. If that's possible with remote *and* it only calls the rule on blur, then I can try for that. (All of my AJAX responses adhere to a set object definition.)

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="register-wizard">User ID:
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control required confirm-me" id="User_UserId" name="User.UserId" autocomplete="off" />
    <div class="loader user-id hide" style="display: none;"><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large"></i> (Checking...)</div>
    <p>
        <button id="next">Next</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $wizardForm = $("#register-wizard");
var $validator = $wizardForm.validate({
    rules: {
        "User.UserId": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 125,
            userIdCheck: true
        }
    }
});

$("#next").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    //do validations before moving onto the next tab in the wizard
    var $valid = $wizardForm.valid();
    if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
    }
});    
jQuery.validator.addMethod("userIdCheck", function (value, element) {
    var validator = this;
    this.startRequest(element);    
    var $loader = $(".loader.user-id");    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            json: JSON.stringify({
                text: 'some text'
            }),
            delay: 1
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("result: ")
            console.log(result);

            validator.stopRequest(element, true);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("A server error occurred.\n\n" + textStatus);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $loader.show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $loader.hide();
        }
    });

return "pending";
}, "The user ID is already in use");
```

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eHu35/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote Title**:  *"one rule on blur only; the rest should be normal?"*

No, the various triggering events, like `onfocusout`, `onkeyup`, etc., are triggered on a "per field" basis.  You cannot have one rule on a field, say `min`, triggered normally on all events, while another rule for the same field, say `remote`, is triggered only by `onfocusout`.  (*You can, however, have different events for different fields*).

In most of the SO threads on this topic I've seen, the user will disable `onkeyup` in order to prevent the constant premature triggering of the `remote` rule.  When testing a re-captcha code, for example, disabling `onkeyup` is required as a new code is generated every time one fails.

Comment: Hmm, I have seen this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372131/trigger-only-some-of-the-rules-of-a-textbox-in-form-validation-with-keyup-event?rq=1) and see the onkeyup handling. I was hoping that I could also check for a particular rule in there.

Comment: @DougS, Upon a triggering event, the rules are evaluated.  Nothing is evaluated regarding the rules/element/value until _after_ the trigger, by this time, you cannot block something that's already happened!

Comment: since this is a throw-away demo- I'm likely going to just leave it be. I think ultimately that I'm going to have to extract this  piece of the validation out of JQuery validate and handle it separately. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered the same problem, and use this way works, not use the remote method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("userIdCheck", function(value, element, params) {
    if (event.type == "blur" || event.type == "focusout") {
        var result;
        $.ajax({url: "path", async: false,
                success: function(data){
                  result = data;
              }})
        return result;
    } else {
        return true;
    }       
}, "The user ID is already in use");
```

But this don't work on firefox, event undefined. So I modefied the source code(anyone has another way?):

```
function delegate( event ) {
    var validator = $.data( this[ 0 ].form, "validator" ),
        eventType = "on" + event.type.replace( /^validate/, "" ),
        settings = validator.settings;
        // add event to validator
        validator.event = event;
        if ( settings[ eventType ] && !this.is( settings.ignore ) ) {
            settings[ eventType ].call( validator, this[ 0 ], event );
        }
    }
```

then we can use in this way:

```
$.validator.addMethod("userIdCheck", function(value, element, params) {
    var eventType = this.event.type;
    if (eventType == "blur" || eventType == "focusout") {
        var result;
        $.ajax({url: "path", async: false,
                success: function(data){
                  result = data;
              }})
        return result;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "The user ID is already in use");
```

Not prefect enough, but this is the only way I find to solve this problem.

Comment: if not blur event(most is keyup event) just return true, when catch the blur event go ajax validate the data.