# jQuery Validate remote onblur only but allow onkeyup for rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to do a jquery remote validation to see if a name is unique or not, but i do not want to do remote validation on every single onkekup event, however i would like to do this on blur event(when user leaves the textbox). but with current code i have below, it fires up after 2nd character is pressed. i would like to continue to have rest of the rules fire on onkeyup like required and minlength and rules for other elements.
**is there not a property to control this behavior, just for single rule? i noticed a set default that does for entire form.**

```
  elem.validate({
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 60,
                remote: {
                    url: "/api/IsUniqueName",
                    onkeyup: false,
                    type: "get",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: {
                        name: function () {

                            return elem.find('input[name^=Name]').val();
                        }
                    },
                    headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken: Indexreqtoken
                    },
                }
            },
            ...
```

Comment: Do you need both event listeners on the same element? Because I am not sure you can do that with jQuery.validate. If it is the same element, have you considered setting a timeout in a loop so that if the user keeps typing within that timeframe the validation doesn't fire? With this method, you could tie both validation checks to the same keyup event, and prevent excessive communication with the remove server.

Comment: in my elem.validate elem is the form id, and has multiple element. if i can control by element for on blur vs onkeyp i am open to that idea as well but how would i do so?

Comment: If this is the jQuery plugin you are using (http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), try looking into the `onfocusout` event (http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout). So, basically, you can run all your checks `onblur` instead of most of them `onkeyup` and only one `onblur`.

Comment: @Marventus, the `onfocusout` event is enabled by default.  In other words, the OP does not need to activate this feature.

Comment: @Sparky, cool, I wasn't 100% sure of that. In any case, I think it would make more sense (and it would be simpler and cleaner) to stick to only one event. What do you think?

Comment: @Marventus, many people simply disable `onkeyup` for the whole form since it is very simple to do.  However, it's not that complicated to disable it for a certain field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot put the `onkeyup` option inside of the `remote` rule... that's not how the `remote` method works.  [The `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) can only accept the same options as jQuery `.ajax()` and nothing else.

**However, you cannot restrict or control the triggering events on a "per rule" basis.**  These events are captured for the whole form or individually on each field, they can not be confined to a specific rule.

If you want to restrict the plugin's `onkeyup` function to certain fields, then you would use a conditional within the `onkeyup` option...

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
        if ($(element).attr('name') == "name") {
            return false; // disable onkeyup for your element named as "name"
        } else { // else use the default on everything else
            if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue( element ) === "" ) {
                return;
            } else if ( element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastElement ) {
                this.element( element );
            }
        }
    },
    ignore: [],  // <- note the proper format for the "ignore nothing" setting.
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 60,
            remote: {
                url: "/api/IsUniqueName",
                ....
```

---

**EDIT:**

**Quote OP**:

> *"is there not a property to control this behavior, just for single rule?"*

No, the triggering events cannot be controlled on a "per rule" basis.  They can only be controlled for the whole form OR for a specific field, as I've shown above.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21313848/594235