# jQuery Remote Validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that uses the jQuery validation plugin and it takes in two inputs. One input is the article title and the other is the article URL. The article title is required and must have a minimum of 10 characters. The URL is the same, but with the URL it checks if the URL is taken or not. Normally, when I submit a title and a URL that isn't taken, it submits correctly. When I add a title and then a URL that's taken and then click away from the input form, it works and tells me that this url is already taken. The problem occurs when I input a title and then a URL that's taken, and then clicking submit. The information is submitted successfully as if the user did not enter a URL that's taken. The error message shows only after I click submit. This problem occurs only when I input a title, a URL that's taken and then directly hitting the submit button without clicking away from the form. How do I fix this problem? Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form class="article_information_form" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

  <p>Title</p>
  <input id="articleTitle" type="text" name="articleTitle" maxlength="75" required>

  <p style="clear: both">Article URL</p>
  <input id="articleUrl" type="text" name="articleUrl" maxlength="65" required>

  <input id="btn" type="submit" name="article_info_btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
$(".article_information_form").validate({
  errorElement: 'div',
  rules: {
    articleTitle: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10
    },
    articleUrl: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      remote: {
        url: "urlChecker.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          articleUrl: function() {
            return $("#articleUrl").val();

          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  messages: {
    articleTitle: {
      required: "You have to provide a title for your article!",
      minlength: "Your title must be at least 10 characters long"
    },

    articleUrl: {
      required: "Please enter a URL for your article",
      minlength: "Your URL must be at least 10 characters long",
      remote: "This URL is already taken! Try another."
    },
  },

});

$('.article_information_form').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    if ($('.article_information_form').valid())
                    {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                          }
                    });
                    }               
                });
```

**urlChecker.php Code**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require "../connect.php";

    if (isset($_POST["articleUrl"]))
    {
        $url = filter_data(friendlyUrl($_POST["articleUrl"]));
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Stories WHERE url = '$url'");

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $output = false;
        }

        else
        {
            $output = true;
        }



        echo json_encode($output);
    }


    function filter_data($data)
    {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
    }

    function friendlyUrl ($str = '') {

        $friendlyURL = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false); 
        $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|circ|lig|grave|ring|tilde|uml|cedil|caron);/i','\1',$friendlyURL);
        $friendlyURL = html_entity_decode($friendlyURL,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"); 
        $friendlyURL = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $friendlyURL);
        $friendlyURL = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $friendlyURL);
        $friendlyURL = trim($friendlyURL, '-');
        $friendlyURL = strtolower($friendlyURL);
        return $friendlyURL;

    }


?>
```

To summarize the problem, URL validation works correctly when I click out of the form. If I enter a URL that already exists and I immediately click submit, it will not work.

Comment: You mean to say that remote validation for URL triggers on focusout, right?

Comment: @chirag Yes, that's whats happening

Comment: It is a default behavior of jQuery validation. Refer these links from SO [jQuery Validate remote onblur only but allow onkeyup for rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612695/jquery-validate-remote-onblur-only-but-allow-onkeyup-for-rest)  and  [one rule on blur only; the rest should be normal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299574/jquery-validate-one-rule-on-blur-only-the-rest-should-be-normal/21313848) You can also check this [Demo](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/captcha/) by jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to happen.  If the user goes straight for the submit button, how do you prevent him?  What event would be triggered when the user does not click on another field?  There's no event that "knows" when the user is completely done typing in a field until they click something else.  Regardless, since the validation test is triggered when the user clicks submit, the form will stop on this remote error and give a message, which is what happens now.